# Retrieving constraints from GADT to ensure exhaustion of pattern matching in Coq

Tags: coq, dependent-type, gadt

Let's define two helper types:

```
Inductive AB : Set := A | B.
Inductive XY : Set := X | Y.
```

Then two other types that depend on `XY` and `AB`

```
Inductive Wrapped : AB -> XY -> Set :=
| W : forall (ab : AB) (xy : XY), Wrapped ab xy
| WW : forall (ab : AB), Wrapped ab (match ab with A => X | B => Y end)
.

Inductive Wrapper : XY -> Set :=
  WrapW : forall (xy : XY), Wrapped A xy -> Wrapper xy.
```

Note the `WW` constructor – it can only be value of types `Wrapped A X` and `Wrapped B Y`.

Now I would like to pattern match on `Wrapper Y`:

```
Definition test (wr : Wrapper Y): nat :=
  match wr with
  | WrapW Y w =>
    match w with
    | W A Y => 27
    end
  end.
```

but I get error

```
Error: Non exhaustive pattern-matching: no clause found for pattern WW _
```

Why does it happen? `Wrapper` forces contained `Wrapped` to be `A` version, the type signature forces `Y` and `WW` constructor forbids being `A` and `Y` simultaneously. I don't understand why this case is being even considered, while I am forced to check it which seems to be impossible.

How to workaround this situation?

Comment: What about W A X in the inner match? Did you mean to provide a branch for that?

Comment: W A X will be illegal here since I take Wrapper Y if I am right

Comment: Oh yes, you're right.

Comment: I think the problem is that `match` is actually more low-level than one might think. Consider using the Equations plugin for more ergonomic pattern-matching. https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple but tricky:

```
Definition test (wr : Wrapper Y): nat.
  refine (match wr with
  | WrapW Y w =>
    match w in Wrapped ab xy return ab = A -> xy = Y -> nat with
    | W A Y => fun _ _ => 27
    | _ => fun _ _ => _
    end eq_refl eq_refl
  end);
[ | |destruct a]; congruence.
Defined.
```

The issue was that Coq didn't infer some necessary invariants to realize that `WW` case is ridiculous. I had to explicitly give it a proof for it.

In this solution I changed `match` to return a function that takes two proofs and brings them to the context of our actual result:

- `ab` is apparently `A`
- `xy` is apparently `Y`

I have covered real cases ignoring these assumptions, and I deferred "bad" cases to be proven false later which turned to be trivial. I was forced to pass the `eq_refl`s manually, but it worked and does not look that bad.

Answer (score 3):

Let's simplify:

```coq
Inductive MyTy : Set -> Type :=
  MkMyTy : forall (A : Set), A -> MyTy A.

Definition extract (m : MyTy nat) : nat :=
  match m with MkMyTy _ x => S x end.
```

This fails:

```
The term "x" has type "S" while it is expected to have type "nat".
```

wat.

This is because I said

```coq
Inductive MyTy : Set -> Type
```

This made the first argument to `MyTy` an index of `MyTy`, as opposed to a parameter. An inductive type with a parameter may look like this:

```coq
Inductive list (A : Type) : Type :=
  | nil : list A
  | cons : A -> list A -> list A.
```

Parameters are named on the left of the `:`, and are not `forall`-d in the definition of each constructor. (They are still present in the constructors' types outside of the definition: `cons : forall (A : Type), A -> list A -> list A`.) If I make the `Set` a parameter of `MyTy`, then `extract` can be defined:

```coq
Inductive MyTy (A : Set) : Type :=
  MkMyTy : A -> MyTy A.

Definition extract (m : MyTy nat) : nat :=
  match m with MkMyTy _ x => S x end.
```

The reason for this is that, on the inside, a `match` *ignores* anything you know about the indices of the scrutinee from the outside. (Or, rather, the underlying `match` expression in Gallina ignores the indices. When you write a `match` in the source code, Coq tries to convert it into the primitive form while incorporating information from the indices, but it often fails.) The fact that `m : MyTy nat` in the first version of `extract` simply did not matter. Instead, the match gave me `S : Set` (the name was automatically chosen by Coq) and `x : S`, as per the constructor `MkMyTy`, with no mention of `nat`. Meanwhile, because `MyTy` has a parameter in the second version, I actually get `x : nat`. The `_` is really a placeholder this time; it is mandatory to write it as `_`, because there's nothing to match, and you can `Set Asymmetric Patterns` to make it disappear.

The reason we distinguish between parameters and indices is because parameters have a lot of restrictions—most notably, if `I` is an inductive type with parameters, then the parameters must appear as variables in the return type of each constructor:

```coq
Inductive F (A : Set) : Set := MkF : list A -> F (list A).
                                            (* ^--------^ BAD: must appear as F A *)
```

In your problem, we should make parameters where we can. E.g. the `match wr with Wrap Y w => _ end` bit is wrong, because the `XY` argument to `Wrapper` is an index, so the fact that `wr : Wrapper Y` is ignored; you would need to handle the `Wrap X w` case too. Coq hasn't gotten around to telling you that.

```coq
Inductive Wrapped (ab : AB) : XY -> Set :=
| W : forall (xy : XY), Wrapped ab xy
| WW : Wrapped ab (match ab with A => X | B => Y end).

Inductive Wrapper (xy : XY) : Set := WrapW : Wrapped A xy -> Wrapper xy.
```

And now your `test` compiles (almost):

```coq
Definition test (wr : Wrapper Y): nat :=
  match wr with
  | WrapW _ w => (* mandatory _ *)
    match w with
    | W _ Y => 27 (* mandatory _ *)
    end
  end.
```

because having the parameters gives Coq enough information for its `match`-elaboration to use information from `Wrapped`'s index. If you issue `Print test.`, you can see that there's a bit of hoop-jumping to pass information about the index `Y` through the primitive `match`s which would otherwise ignore it. [See the reference manual for more information.](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/extended-pattern-matching.html)

Comment: What if `Wrapped` had yet another constructor `WWW : Wrapped A Y`? Wouldn't it break the idea?

Comment: Yes, then you'd have to keep the `AB` as an index and probably manually write out a `match w in Wrapped ab xy return _ with ...`, as in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the precise explanation that distinguishes the user-level match and the kernel-level match! I sometimes find confusing how different both are in certain cases.